# Multiple calls to a Rhino mocked method return different results

Tags: rhino-mocks

If I want to mock a class that returns a string that is used to determine whether while loop should continue (imagine read while string != null), how can I set the expectation. I have tried the following:

```
    provider.Reader.Expect(r => r.ReadLine()).Return("1,10,20");
    provider.Reader.Expect(r => r.ReadLine()).Return(null);
```

but when it is called twice in the same method, it returns the first string on both occasions, whereas I want it to return the second value (null) if called a second time.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I think you can just stick the repeat on the end of the syntax you're currently using.

```
provider.Reader.Expect(r => r.ReadLine()).Return("1,10,20").Repeat.Once();
provider.Reader.Expect(r => r.ReadLine()).Return(null).Repeat.Once();
```

or

```
 provider.Reader.Expect(r => r.ReadLine()).Return("1,10,20").Repeat.Once();
    provider.Reader.Expect(r => r.ReadLine()).Return(null);
```

if you have any calls beyond 2nd call that you want to use second expectation.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the syntax you're using. I would write this as:

```
r.ReadLine();
LastCall.Return("1,10,20").Repeat.Once();
r.ReadLine();
LastCall.Return(null).Repeat.Once();
```

To ensure that you're specifying the number of times that things are to be repeated. (Don't have Visual Studio to hand, syntax may not be exact.)

Comment: This is the 3.5 fluent syntax.