# Unit test, Rhino, The art of unit testing

Tags: unit-testing, testing, mocking, rhino-mocks, rhino

I've started to read "The art of unit testing" and I'm trying to implement this piece of code:

```
[Test]
public void ReturnResultsFromMock()
{
    MockRepository mocks = new MockRepository();
    IGetResults resultGetter = mocks.DynamicMock<IGetResults>();
    using(mocks.Record())
     {
        resultGetter.GetSomeNumber("a");//#1
        LastCall.Return(1);
        resultGetter.GetSomeNumber("a");//#2 how it should work?
        LastCall.Return(2);
        resultGetter.GetSomeNumber("b");
        LastCall.Return(3);
    }
    int result = resultGetter.GetSomeNumber("b");
    Assert.AreEqual(3, result);
    int result2 = resultGetter.GetSomeNumber("a");
    Assert.AreEqual(1, result2);
    int result3 = resultGetter.GetSomeNumber("a");
    Assert.AreEqual(2, result3);
}
```

I get this error message after running my test
*AOUT.Loga.Tests.LogAnalyzerTest.ReturnResultsFromMock:
  Expected: 2
  But was:  1*

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you try to implement *ordered* sequence of calls (see details [here](http://ayende.com/wiki/Rhino%20Mocks%20Ordered%20and%20Unordered.ashx)):

- First you call `GetSomeNumber("a")` should returns 1
- Then call `GetSomeNumber("a")` again, result will be 2
- And only then `GetSomeNumber("b")`, result will be 3

Is so, try to replace `using(mocks.Record())` with `using(mocks.Ordered())`. But, this will work only in this sequence of calls

At your example, you are using `using(mocks.Record())`, so every call to `GetSomeNumber("a")` will return 2 acording to your configuration. You're override first `GetSomeNumber("a")` by second one. Here are correct assumptions:

```
int result = resultGetter.GetSomeNumber("b");
Assert.AreEqual(3, result);
int result2 = resultGetter.GetSomeNumber("a");
Assert.AreEqual(2, result2); // every call to GetSomeNumber("a") will returns 2
int result3 = resultGetter.GetSomeNumber("a");
Assert.AreEqual(2, result3);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try using the simpler [Rhino Mocks AAA syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2124175/rhino-mocks-aaa-quick-start), your code will look something like this (take a look also at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1468226/multiple-calls-to-a-rhino-mocked-method-return-different-results)):

```
    // Arrange
    var resultGetter = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IGetResults>;
    resultGetter.Expect(x => x.GetSomeNumber("b")).Return(3);
    resultGetter.Expect(x => x.GetSomeNumber("a")).Return(1).Repeat.Once();
    resultGetter.Expect(x => x.GetSomeNumber("b")).Return(2).Repeat.Once();

    // Act
    int result = resultGetter.GetSomeNumber("b");
    // Assert
    Assert.AreEqual(3, result);
    // Act
    int result2 = resultGetter.GetSomeNumber("a");
    // Assert
    Assert.AreEqual(1, result2);
    // Act
    int result3 = resultGetter.GetSomeNumber("a");
    // Assert
    Assert.AreEqual(2, result3);
```